Finite open cover of a compact Hausdorff space admits a closed shrinking?
Assume $X$ is compact Hausdorff. If there is a finite open cover $\{U_i\}$, prove that there is a finite closed cover $\{F_i\}$ such that $F_i\subseteq U_i$.
I have no idea how to prove it.
Edit: There is a more general statement saying that a point-finite open cover in a normal space admits a closed shrinking, which can be proved by Zorn's lemma. But there should be a direct proof of this question?

You have $X = \bigcup_{i=1}^n U_i$ for some collection of $n$ open subsets of $X$. Can you use the $U_i$s to produce any closed sets?

I would start with the case $n = 2$. This is already a nontrivial fact - try taking complements and seeing if you recognise what the statement becomes...

This is proven in Dugundji's Topology. The proof for normal spaces should translate nicely for the proof for finite covers... just go by induction. You consider cover by $U_1, ..., U_n$, shrink first one to $V_1$, $\overline{V_1}\subseteq U_1$, so that $V_1, U_2, ..., U_n$ is a cover, and so on.

Every compact Hausdorff space is regular. That is for a point $x$ inside open set $U$ there is open set $V$ such that $x\in V$ and $\overline{V}\subseteq U$. This is shown as a first step in the standard proof that compact Hausdorff spaces are normal.
Now go through your covering, for each $U$ go through its points and pick the corresponding $V$. Next pick a finite subcover of newly formed $V$ cover. And finally go through the initial cover one more time and take unions of (now finite number of) $V$ per given $U$ (which potentially can give the empty set by the way). $F$ will be the closure of that union. This works because closure of union is union of closures in finite case.
And yes, this does not require Zorn's lemma. Neither does the fact that every compact Hausdorff space is Tychonoff, as far as I know. Compactness is often strong enough to avoid the Axiom of Choice.

I don't see why go through Tychonoff spaces. The standard proof that compact Hausdorff spaces are normal is to first prove that they are regular - which is exactly the only thing you need here. I hope you don't mind if I edit that out. Anyway, nice proof that compact regular spaces are shrinkable.

@Jakobian that's fine. I just wanted to point out to a stronger property that holds. Either way it works.
